# Is there a way to send a conversation unique identifier to the Twilio webhook?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to uniquely identify the conversation an SMS is replying to without having to buy a new 'from' phone number each time.  I know that one can store whatever you want in cookie or session storage, but those both expire in different ways.  What I really want is somehow to pass or use an existing unique id for each separate conversation.  So that I can map the messages to the right conversations.

I'm not sure but I wonder if its possible to send a expireless unique identifier to a webhook. So that I know which conversation it should be mapped to?

If not is there some way to use the conversation api to achieve the effect of tracking which sms messages belong to which conversations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common challenge, since SMS is a stateless, is to try and match up the specific request with the  response. [Twilio Studio's](https://www.twilio.com/studio) [Send and Wait for Reply](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-wait-reply) widget does this by only allowing one sent message (to the destination number) until there is a response OR the configurable timeout parameter expires, and then moving to the next widget, so keeping state of the interaction.

As you said, if you are attempting to have multiple simultaneous threads to the same destination phone number, you will need to use a unique From number to separate out the threads - from the received parties perspective, they don't see threading in their SMS client, and cannot pick which question to respond to.

[image]

[image]

[Best Practices for SMS Message Logging](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/outbound-message-logging#additional-questions)

> Additional Questions Q: Can a user send a customer identifier for a
>   message, or is only the Twilio-defined SID available?
>
> A: Only the Twilio-defined SID is available.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Ah, fundamentally you have to have one phone number per thread because otherwise there's no way for the user's phone to organize the messages.  I guess its not possible to figure out what Message SId started a thread?

Comment: Does the conversation api have any solutions for this problem or does it suffer from the same issue because of the stateless nature of smses?